# What dialect should I use for r2dbc postgresql init.sql?

Tags: r2dbc-postgresql

The problem is: I need to create a function.
If I call it in Idea Postgre console - it works
If I add it to init.sql - it fails with $$ tag

```
create or replace function work(i integer) returns integer
language sql as
$$
select user_id from ttable;
$$
```

I need to know how to make r2dbc use the original syntax in init.sql